# VideoJs Width Height Issue

Tags: css, video.js

I am trying to work with a video and having it render on the website.

I am not allowed to post the video for legal reasons but have some questions re the width and height of the actual video.

The Original height and width of the video are 960 x 540, and they want it on the website rendering at a 1/3 less height with the video being full width (without black bars on the outside).

I keep explaining that when you scale down the height, the width has to go proportionately so that the video stays in scale.

They showed me examples like this:
http://pillar.mediumra.re/home-landing-service-3.html but fail to understand that the video on the header is cropped from the inital value, and which uses object-fit, which doesn't work in IE11,etc.

Is there anything else i can do or change in the css to make this work.

I tried rescaling the video in VLC and using that but it gets all pixely and when i do the videojs class vjs-16-9 it will be the same height of the previous video.

Also the video is a 18mb video, i tried using the vimeo vjs plugin instead to acommodate less bandwidth but when you hover on the video it will show the control bar from vimeo and i assume they wouldn't want that.

I also tried playing with certain css class' but it doesn't scale down correctly (has the black bars).

```
/* Video Code Changes */
.video-js.vjs-fill{
 /* max-height:250px !important;   */
}   
.video-js .vjs-tech{
 /* max-height:75% !important;  */
}
/* end Video Code changes */
```

Code below For reference (any ideas):

```
 <video id="my-video" class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-16-9" preload="auto" poster="MY_VIDEO_POSTER.jpg"  data-setup='{"controls": false, "autoplay": true, "preload": "auto", "muted": true, "loop": true}'>

                            <source src="content/video/video_hi.mp4" type='video/mp4' >


                        <p class="vjs-no-js">
                            To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that
                            <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a>
                        </p>
                    </video>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They understood what I explained, and the idea they want cannot be achieved.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to create a wrapper element, let's call it `.video-wrapper` and put the `video` tag inside it.

```
<div class="video-wrapper">
  <video src="..." autoplay></video>
</div>
```

You can then give the wrapper element the preferred height, center its children (similar to `background-position: center`) and hide the overflow. The `video` element now only needs to fill the width of the parent and you should be done.

```
.video-wrapper {
  height: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.video-wrapper > video {
  width: 100%;
}
```

*You can take a look at my [CodePen](http://cdpn.io/e/xPbJeP) to see how the result looks.*

Comment: let me try this and see what happens.

Comment: Ok I tried that idea but now the video has text in the video at certain sections and the text is being cropped. the video needs to show all the video content and cannot have stuff clipped off. That's what i am confused about.

Comment: Doesn't some stuff have to be clipped off? Otherwise you'd have to stretch the video which would look bad.

Comment: That's what i keep telling him LOL.

It will be out of scale if not done that way.

So i am right it makes no sense also it has to be responsive and show the video on mobile and desktop etc with the full video showing and nothing cropped off.

Comment: I'd say that's impossible. Either you have a background video just for decoration in which case it doesn't matter when stuff gets cropped off or you have a video where "everything" matters and a nice video player on a good looking background is the only solution.

Comment: So do i tell him that the video can be either 

A. full width but the original height.
B. full width with some info cropped to make it shorter.
C.less than full width but with all info(this wouldn't work )as would have a black background.

The other idea i saw on the other website would be cropping a section of the video and that he didn't seem to get.

Comment: Yeah, I'd do that. And if you still can't convince him that the thing he wants doesn't work, maybe create a quick CodePen example to demonstrate that.

Comment: Ok he is fine with A.

Thanks everyone for the help.